# Accessing a user's history using JS

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, browser-history

**I'm not looking for code/how to. Just knowledge.**

A client has just come to us with a question: Can we access the user's history from within a banner advert to give them some targeted advertising based on their history.

Obviously, this **presents a privacy issue**, but I need to give a good case for why it is technically not a viable option.

So I have a few questions...

1. Which browsers *still*, if any, support accessing a user's history, using `window.history`.
2. If some do and some don't. When did those who don't allow it stop allowing it?
3. If all browsers allow it (I have yet to find a script that works), why is it not commonly used?

Finally,
Having been on Amazon.co.uk, I then go to Macrumors.com and the adverts give me adverts based on products I have bought/looked at. I'm guessing this is just based on cookies/a system that amazon has implemented?

**Just to make things clear:**

- I know it is a privacy issue. I am not looking for code/a way to do it (as I mentioned above)
- There are ways to "sniff" for visited links within a page.
- There used to be a way using the JavaScript `history` object, to list all the objects within your history (from the current site). `history.length` still works now. I seem to remember some browsers only returning `undefined` for each item, some returning them as an unreadable `object`.

Comment: What do you mean with "history"? Do you meean the browser object where you can navigate with back and forward button, or the history of visted sites?

Comment: A history of visited websites...

Comment: It is possible to access the URL of the previously-visited page using [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer), but not the browser's entire history.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No!**

There's no browser (that I know of) that legitimately give you access to a user's browsing history.

There has been [incidents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector) where it was possible to do so by [exploiting certain behaviors of the browser](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/12/05/browser_history_attack_revived/). Recently, in Firefox 16 there's a [vulnerability](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2012/10/10/security-vulnerability-in-firefox-16/) that, if exploited properly, allows you to peek into the user's browsing history.

In the case you're describing (Amazon), yes, cookies are used. To be more accurate, [Third-Party Cookies](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/third-party-cookies/) are used.

**Update:**
I was very interested in your last edit (about `history` being completely open in the past), so I tried to go back a little.

[image: Firefox 3.0.19]

[image]

Comment: Can i also ask why I have been down voted? and why that answer has now been deleted?

Comment: Also, my question is still valid: the window.history object used to be an array of history items (the url was included as part of that). It is now a protected array (run this in firebug: window.history[0])...

So when did it become a protected object that couldn't be accessed, and was it in response to security, privacy or both?

Comment: @sparkyfied, I'm not sure I can answer on behalf of others, but I downvoted it because it's a bit off-topic and I didn't see any effort on your side. As for your new question, you can check the [History Interface specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#the-history-interface)

Comment: I disagree, I have researched this, I know how window.history used to work, but there are certain bits of information I could not find like when browsers stopped supporting this and if any browsers still do support it?

I feel that the answers I have received are not answers based on the question asked, but knee jerk reactions to the privacy issues.

I would humbly request a re-read of the question and a removal of your down vote.

Comment: Also, i'm not sure how this question can be defined as off-topic?

Comment: @sparkyfied, there, I removed my downvote. Anyway, check my last update, it answers your last question.