# Check if last window History is from a certain URL

Tags: javascript, web

Whether possible to **check** if **last browser history** is from **mysite.com**, then `goBack()` else `goHome()` ?

Let's say

- `facebook.com` ~> `mysite.com/page` ~> myBackBtn act as **goHome** or **mysite.com**
- `mysite.com/page` ~> `mysite.com/page2` ~> myBackBtn act as **goBack** or **mysite.com/page**

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/12857601/104380

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) to get the URL of the page that linked to the current page. Note that this is easily spoofed.

That will **only** work if the user followed a link from the previous page to get to the current page. If they used a bookmark, or typed in a URL, etc., `referrer` will be blank and there is **no way** for you to get the information about what was in the window previously. (In particular: There's nothing in the `history` object that will tell you.) That's simply information that is not available in the browser.

Comment: I make SPA, referrer always return empty string

Comment: @DonnyGunawan: That doesn't follow. If I follow a link from Facebook to your SPA, `document.referrer` will be the Facebook URL.

Comment: is document.referrer will be null if the page open in new tab?

Comment: @rifa29 - Please review the documentation linked above.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `document.referrer` and the `history` API for a solution, but note this is not going to work **always**:

```
if (document.referrer === 'my.domain.com') {
   history.back(); // act as if user clicked the browser back button
} 
else {
   window.location.href = 'http://my.domain.com/home';
}
```

Won't work on IE and the `document.referrer` is not always accurate, see single page applications

Comment: yes I make SPA, referrer always return empty string